# PDO com Emulated prepares é inseguro? Qual a diferença?

Tags: php, pdo, segurança

Recentemente fiz algumas pesquisas na internet e notei que várias pessoas dizem que PDO não protege 100% contra injection, especificamente com emulated prepares. Se possível alguém me de um exemplo de SQL que passaria pelo PDO com prepared statement para entender melhor a questão e a diferença de se utilizar o emulated prepare.

Answer (score 8):

### Entendendo *Prepared Statements*

Antes de mais nada, vamos entender o que são os *prepared statements*. Quando você manda uma *query* para o motor da base de dados, seus comandos em SQL são transformados em uma série de "comandos" internos. Simplificando, são compilados.

Normalmente o SQL passa por um *query planner*, que abstrai do programador qual é a melhor maneira de fazer aquela tarefa (quando usar índices, como fazer os *joins*, etc)

Em muitas situações, se percebeu que o custo desta compilação poderia ser evitado em casos de repetição de comandos, como vários inserts em seguida, em casos em que o número de inserções pode variar dinamicamente e não podem ser enviados numa query só, ou em várias consultas com estrutura igual, mas valores variados.

A solução foi separar os valores da consulta propriamente dita, atráves dos *prepared statements*.

Em resumo: você manda a *query* uma vez só, ela é "compilada" uma vez só, e reaproveitada com os valores que você manda em seguida.

### Segurança x Prepared Statements

Vamos esquecer só por um breve instante dos *prepared statements*, e pensar nas injeções de SQL. Normalmente, as *queries* dinâmicas "tradicionais" são montadas como uma concatenação de *string*:

```
$sql = 'SELECT tipo FROM batatas WHERE id='.$_POST['idDaBatata'];
```

Numa situação normal, a aplicação manda um `"7"`, e a *query* fica assim:

```
SELECT tipo FROM batatas WHERE id=7
```

Até aí tudo legal, mas um atacante poderia mandar um `"0; DROP DATABASE;"`:

```
SELECT tipo FROM batatas WHERE id=0; DROP DATABASE;
```

Eis que você tem um problema! (vamos desconsiderar o fato de ser mais de uma *query*, a sintaxe e outras proteções, só quis simplificar o exemplo).

Quando usamos *prepared statements*, o formato muda:

```
$sql = 'SELECT tipo FROM batatas WHERE id=?';
```

Se estamos falando de **prepared statements nativos**, não tem nenhuma concatenação de *string* aqui. Simplesmente reservamos um *placeholder* com a `?`, que receberá o valor.

Quando chamamos o *prepare*, o *engine* do DB vai compilar a *query*, ela vai deixar de ser uma *string* e se transformar numa espécie de "programa" interno.

Para usar este programa, vamos mandar o valor do usuário:

```
funcao_bind_da_lib( $preparado, INTEGER, $_POST['idDaBatata']; );
```

Neste momento, o dado é convertido em um inteiro (poderia ser uma string), e passado como valor, diretamente para o **programa compilado**, e não será reinterpretado. Neste momento, mesmo que fosse uma *string*, um `DROP DATABASE` não teria nenhum significado para o DB, pois já passamos da fase da compilação no passo anterior.

Em resumo, quando usamos *prepared statements* nativos o isolamento é uma consequência "natural", e a segurança um efeito colateral (desejável).

Quando estamos **simulando**, está acontecendo o primeiro exemplo, com *strings*, e do lado do cliente. A nossa *query* passa por um *replace* que troca as interrogações e *placeholders* por *strings*. Os dados que vem do usuário são enviados para a etapa de compilação, e não de execução.

### Então, simular *Prepared Statements* não é seguro?

Calma! Pode ser seguro sim. :)

Desde que o framework/lib usado, faça a "limpeza" das *strings*, evitando o uso indevido de um `;`, funções indesejadas, e caracteres especiais como aspas, etc.

O que é necessário entender é que a proteção "natural" foi perdida, e que tem que ser compensada de alguma maneira. E que aí você passa a depender da qualidade da lib usada, ou se fizer "manualmente", da qualidade do seu código.

No caso específico do PDO, a simulação das queries preparadas e da vinculação de parâmetros, como era de se esperar, já inclui a sanitização das strings do lado do cliente (senão, inclusive, seria uma fonte de dores de cabeça que tornaria seu uso inviável com valores com caracteres especiais, mesmo em seu uso regular).

Sem binding nativo, passa a ser função da lib pegar o dado do usuário, e limpar quaisquer coisas estranhas, pois o DB vai "acreditar cegamente" no que você mandar para ele, como se fossem comandos seus.

E lembrando também que nesse caso, se mandar 40 *queries* em seguida, elas vão ter que ser transmitidas na íntegra ao DB as 40 vezes e compiladas 40 vezes, o que não é um problema de segurança, apenas de performance e arquitetura.

#### E o exemplo que passe pelo PDO?

Esse, felizmente, eu não tenho, afinal de contas, se alguém achar algum, precisa urgentemente mandar pra eles como *bug report*, pois seria uma vulnerabilidade afetando um numero imenso de usuários :)

Comment: Quando você diz "uso indevido de um ;" quer dizer que o exemplo abaixo passaria?  $sql = 'SELECT tipo FROM batatas WHERE id=?';  funcao_bind_da_lib( $preparado, INTEGER, '; DROP...'; );

Comment: Não passa pq o PDO internamente vai por um "escape" em todos os caracteres estranhos, anulando eles. O importante é entender que não é _prepared statement_ quem está te protegendo neste caso, e sim o código do PDO fazendo uma limpeza "manual" internamente. O grande risco de não usar o nativo é que vc fica dependendo do programador da lib ser cuidadoso. Com _prepared nativo_ já não tem muito onde errar. No caso do PDO é claro que tem muitas e muitas pessoas testando pra não passar nada. Mas ter consciência da diferença é bom na hora que você puder escolher entre algo nativo ou não.

Comment: Acho que agora ficou claro, é porque quando você disse "Desde que o framework/lib usado, faça a "limpeza" das strings", achei seria necessário utilizar o PDO + fazer essa limpeza, mas sua frase se referia ao conceito em si, que o próprio PDO já implementa.